# Celery - automatic retrying of long running tasks running on crashed worker

Tags: redis, celery, django-celery

I'm using `Celery` with `Django` over `Redis`.

Some of my tasks are quite long, taking about `1 hour`. I'm aware that this is suboptimal, and preferably I should use shorter tasks, but this is what I got...

Sometimes the task/worker crash. This can happen for various unimportant reasons. Maybe this worker crashed, network problem, spot-instance when preempted, killed by OOM, or any other unexpected reason that I can't "catch" and handle.

I want to make sure the task will be tried again as fast as possible.

I can use `ack_late`, but the problem is that this task has a very long timeout (about 90 minutes), which means that if the task started and the worker crashed after 2 minutes, I will now wait for another 88 minutes until the task will get back to the queue and will start executing again on another worker.

I'm wondering if there exists another solution, that will see the worker "disappeared" and will put the task back in the queue?

Comment: how did you set the timeout? it doesn't make sense that it should wait 88 minutes if the task stopped..

Answer (score 0):

You could give [task_reject_on_worker_lost](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#task-reject-on-worker-lost) a try... It is a tricky one, but have a look...